# Display only records which are not duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I wish to display only records which have no duplicate.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTbl1 
(
    Circuit VARCHAR(55),
    Bandwidth DECIMAL(7,1),
    Unit BIT,
    CurrentID INT,
);

INSERT INTO #TempTbl1
VALUES
    ('28.L9XX.100277..COXC.', 5.0, 0, 3364),
    ('28/LEHZ/010421/121/CFOK', 100.0, 0, 3223),
    ('#2009-191:604', 10.0, 0, 3100),
    ('28.L9XX.100277..COXC.', 100.0, 0, 3364),
    ('#2009-191:604', 150.0, 0, 3100),
    ('00/GIGE/M3283961/395/303/395', 200.0, 1, 4500)
```

I have the following result

```
 Circuit                       Bandwidth    Unit    CurrentID
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 28.L9XX.100277..COXC.          5.0         0       3364
 28/LEHZ/010421/121/CFOK        100.0       0       3223
 #2009-191:604                  10.0        0       3100
 28.L9XX.100277..COXC.          100.0       0       3364
 #2009-191:604                  150.0       0       3100
 00/GIGE/M3283961/395/303/395   200.0       1       4500
```

I would like my result to look like the following. As you can see I only want to display Circuits which occur only once.

```
 Circuit                       Bandwidth    Unit    CurrentID
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 28/LEHZ/010421/121/CFOK        100.0       0       3223
 00/GIGE/M3283961/395/303/395   200.0       1       4500
```

Comment: What happened to `#2009-191:604`? And `28.L9XX.100277..COXC.`?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Your expected results shows 2 circuits, your data shows 4 unique circuits. Can you please clarify.

Comment: @DaleK #2009-191:604? And 28.L9XX.100277..COXC shows up twice with a different bandwidth the original table.  I would like to query these results but only display 28/LEHZ/010421/121/CFOK  and  00/GIGE/M3283961/395/303/395 because it only shows up once.  Does that help?  You guys are very quick in answering.  Unfortunately, My coding example to display here still needs work. I apologize for my confusion.

Comment: Most people read "not display duplicates" as when there is a duplicate to only return 1 row instead of multiple. In your case it seems when there is a duplicate you don't want any row for that circuit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want only the unique circuits then `group by circuit` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select circuit, 
  max(bandwidth) bandwidth, 
  max(cast(unit as integer)) unit, 
  max(cast(currentid as integer)) currentid
from #TempTbl1
group by circuit
having count(*) = 1
```

The aggregation with `MAX()` in the select list will return the column values as there is only 1 value for each circuit.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c2c55e3f3febe20270775865c75189a).
Results:

```
> circuit                      | bandwidth | unit | currentid
> :--------------------------- | :-------- | ---: | --------:
> 00/GIGE/M3283961/395/303/395 | 200.0     |    1 |      4500
> 28/LEHZ/010421/121/CFOK      | 100.0     |    0 |      3223
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE 
   (SELECT count(1)
    FROM yourtable t2
    WHERE t2.circuit = t1.circuit
    AND t2.currentID = t1.currentID) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a uniqueness per CurrentID & Circuit?

Then a COUNT OVER them should be 1.

```
;WITH CTE_CIRCUITS AS
(
    SELECT *
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CurrentID, Circuit) AS Cnt
    FROM #TempTbl1
)
SELECT Circuit, Bandwidth, Unit, CurrentID
FROM CTE_CIRCUITS
WHERE Cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code if we use `currentid` as a unique field.

```
WITH CTE
 AS (SELECT circuit, 
            FIRST_VALUE(bandwidth) OVER(PARTITION BY currentid
            ORDER BY currentid) bandwidth, 
            FIRST_VALUE(unit) OVER(PARTITION BY currentid
            ORDER BY currentid) unit, 
            currentid, 
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY currentid
            ORDER BY currentid) CNT
     FROM #TempTbl1)
 SELECT circuit, 
        bandwidth, 
        unit, 
        currentid
 FROM CTE
 WHERE CNT = 1;
```

OR:

```
SELECT circuit, 
       bandwidth, 
       unit, 
       currentid
FROM #TempTbl1
WHERE currentid NOT IN
(
    SELECT currentid
    FROM #TempTbl1
    GROUP BY currentid
    HAVING COUNT(currentid) > 1
);
```